# Need to Submit a POST request to "/..." with the following data in form-data: React Native

Tags: form-data, postdata

Need to Submit a POST request to "/..." with the following data in form-data: React Native.

```
 firstName: text,
 middleName: text,
 lastName: text,
 email: text,
 country: text Alpha-3 country code (e.g. EGY or DEU),
 phone: text,
 dob: text Date of birth (format YYYY-mm-dd, e.g. 2001-09-25).,
 gender: text,
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use FormData.

```
import FormData from 'FormData';

var data = new FormData();
data.append("firstname", "abc");
fetch('YOUR_URL', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
    body:data,
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
    console.log('response object:',responseJson)
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```